# How to require the Java Plugin in a firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, manifest

I have written a firefox extension which requires the Java plugin in order to run. How can I require the user to install the plugin in order for the application to install.

I have seen that there's a  property in the install.rdf file but I'm not sure whether it's still available in recent firefox version. If it is available, does the Java plugin have and ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do anything before installation. Once the add-on is installed you can check whether Java is available and display a message (maybe suggest opening a page where the user can get this plugin).

The dependencies mechanism only allowed extensions to depend on other extensions, not on plugins. Also, this mechanism has been removed in Firefox 4.